# Item-value shows when selected instead of item-text, why?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, combobox, vuetify.js

I want the item-text to be shown instead of the item-value, but I havent found a solution yet.

```
    <v-combobox v-model="searchVm.contains.status"
                :items="statuses"
                label="Status"
                item-text= "name"
                item-value= "id"
                :return-object="false"></v-combobox>
```

Comment: I want the item-value(id) to be returned to the searchVm.contains.status, so no.

Answer (score 0):

welcome,

you can see this example will help you [see example](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/combobox)

Comment: I cant see any possible solution there.

Comment: where you are a  component "combobox"? I will see it.

Comment: and can you use Select Options Component instead of creat that component "combobox"